# Move to closest node

Tags: nodes, anylogic

In my model I want the agent to move to a node based on the distance between the agents and some specific nodes in a collection.
So in the moveto block the node is based on a specification function ( see first image), which should be based on a function in anylogic which calculates the distance. Now my idea is to create a function which loops through all nodes in the specific collection and choose the closest based on the getdistance() function (see picture 2). But I'm not sure how to finish it to let the function return the closest node (in the collection) when it is activated in the destination node part.

I also was thinking about using the function getNearestNode which may be helpfull(but the node should be in a specific collection? Can somebody help me, cause I was also not able to find any examples on the internet.

Thanks!

[image: Node movetoblock]

[image: Function]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it like this, just place this on your node section that you circled:

```
top(collectionOfNodes,n->-agent.getDistance(n.getX(),n.getY()))
```

If you want to find the ones that are on the same z then:

```
top(findAll(collectionOfNodes,a->a.getZ()==agent.getZ()),n->-agent.getDistance(n.getX(),n.getY()))
```

Comment: I tried this but he gives the next error: Description: The method getY() is undefined for the type Node.

Comment: Changed the collection to type Rectangularnodes and it worked! One think you also need to change is fill in the agent.getX() and agent.getY() in the get distance. (e.g. top(CollectionNodes,n->-agent.getDistance(agent.getX(), agent.getY(), n.getX(), n.getY())))

Comment: Is it also possible to add something that checks if the location is on the same Z level, since now he sometimes takes nodes which are closer, but not in the same network because they have another Z-level

Comment: @AronT. i updated the answer to take into account the same level nodes

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through all the nodes in the collection and record the distance to a variable called `dist` by using `dist.add(Agent.getDistance(currNode))`. Then pick the index of the minimum.

```
int indexMin=0;
float min = dist.get(0);

for (int i=0; i<dist.size(); ++i) {
        if (min > dist.get(i)) {
                    min = dist.get(i);
                    indexMin = i;
        }
}
```

Now you know that the index of the node with the minimum distance is `indexMin`. You can assign the node with index of indexMin in your collection as destination.